# What is a good reason if the data from analysis and measurement does not give a good agreement?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, data

Currently I am doing a comparison results between analytical results and measurement results, I compare stress and strain values in 32 specified locations, unfortunately I found that there are some locations does not give a good agreement.
and my professor want me to think about the reason, instead of modifying the model,
does anyone come up with an idea about a good reason for this problem?
Thank you
Cindy

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a homework problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possibilities come to mind:

One, the assumptions / theory / model is not describing / modelling the situation correctly,

Or,

Two, the source data is incorrect / has an error at those locations - perhaps the sensors are not mounted the same or the mounting points have been damaged / moved or the calibration for each sensor has drifted.

Comment: wow.. I like the second option. thank you SolarMike.. I really appreciate that

Comment: By the way, check and confirm both sides : physical experiment and the model...

Comment: because now only 6 points show different values, and out of 6 points, only 2 points which show extreme different values. so I start wondering why could that happen and what is the possible reason for this

Comment: You left out the most important possibility:   sophons     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three-Body_Problem_(novel)